# Material ui Autocomplete text getting disappeared after selecting the option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, material-ui, jsx

**Front-End [ Face Error]**

I am trying to create an Autocomplete using material ui but text in input-text getting disappeared after selecting any option. Also variable 'batsmanOrBowler' gets set as 0 after selecting any option.

**Backend :**
Calling the backend service. In postman the response looks like this -

```
[
    {
        "striker": "SC Ganguly"
    },
    {
        "striker": "BB McCullum"
    },
    {
        "striker": "RT Ponting"
    },
    {
        "striker": "DJ Hussey"
    },
]
```

```
export const LoadService = () => {
    return myAxios
        .get(`/load`)
        .then((response) => response.data);
};
```

This seems alright -

```
  const [jsonRes, setJsonRes] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    LoadService()
      .then((data) => {
        setJsonRes(data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
```

'batsmanOrBowler' here-

```
<Autocomplete
                        disablePortal
                        id="combo-box-demo"
                        options={jsonRes.striker ? jsonRes.striker : jsonRes}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.striker}
                        sx={{ width: 300 }}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                          <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />
                        )}
                        name="batsmanOrBowler"
                        placeholder="Batsman"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, "batsmanOrBowler")}
                        value={data.batsmanOrBowler || null}
                      />
```

edit: One part of the problem is solved by Jack and Jagroop. The other part is solved by replacing 'onChange' with 'onSelect'.
Problem is fixed. Thanks...

Comment: Hi  change value as      value={
    jsonRes.find((option) => option.striker === data.batsmanOrBowler) ||
    null
  }

Comment: Hi @Jagroop i tried but getting the same error.

Comment: Hi @Jagroop just noticed, your solutions also solves a part of the problem, thanks.